# CPU frequency or voltage optimization

Tags: linux, performance, cpu, temperature

I'm running a CPU-bound code with OpenMPI on my old Linux server (Core i7-3770, 4 cores with HT).

It works fine, but I found CPU throttling sometimes occurred and the overall performance decreased because of high temperature of CPU.
Now, the CPU frequency governor is in the "ondemand" mode.

The most straightforward way to manage it must be to replace the CPU fan, for example, to cool the CPU.

However, I wonder I could optimize the CPU frequency to keep CPU% to 100, avoiding CPU throttling.

My questions are

1. Is it reasonable to optimize the CPU freq to avoid throttling? Or, should I simply rely on the governor in the "ondemand" mode? (If possible,) Which mode is expected to work higher performance?
2. If the freq optimization could be an option, how should I do? Any auto-optimization code?

Comment: First clean the dust out of the metal fins in your heat sinks.  (You can just use a vacuum cleaner if you don't have a can of compressed air.  Put a finger on the fan to avoid over-speeding the bearings.)  If that's not enough, you should be able to set a custom upper limit on CPU frequency.  That stops it from taking advantage of thermal headroom for bursty or low-power loads, but lower frequency does improve work / energy as well as lowering power, so slow and steady wins the race for long-running "heavy" computations.  Lower it so thermal throttling rarely happens in your normal workloads.

Comment: Thank you for your very quick response! I already cleaned up the metal fins, but no joy. (I use an accessory fan.) So, maybe I should do cpufreq-set -f 2G -c 0 -g userspace, or something. Then, how should I find the best freq? Just keep trying in hand?

Comment: If there's a governor that can aim for a target temperature, that could be perfect to avoid throttling.  Otherwise, any fixed upper-limit frequency is going to depend on the workload.  (e.g. Prime95 is just about the max heat workload for any given frequency with 256-bit SIMD FMA per clock cycle.  Actually your Ivy Bridge CPU doesn't support FMA, but 1x 256-bit FP MUL + 1x 256-bit FP ADD per clock is still pretty high throughput that most code would struggle to achieve on that CPU.)  Maybe someone with more experience with Linux governors can suggest something.

Comment: I'm just an end user of the code and also not familiar with both hardware and software, but try to tweak it. Anyway, thank you so much.

Comment: Look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/587978/can-i-upper-limit-the-cpu-frequency which suggests you can limit the upper frequency.

Comment: You don't really have to know the details of how the software works internally, you just have to be aware that different programs might use different amounts of power (turning it into heat) at the same frequency.  And thus their ideal frequencies could be different.  This can also apply to different phases of the same computation, in which case it would be really nice to have a governor able to bump up the frequency a bit when it's been running all cores for several seconds but still not close to halting the clock to cool off.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say throttling, you mean like kernel log messages about the CPU hitting its "critical" temperature limit, and the CPU clock halting temporarily or dropping to idle speed to cool down?  Because normally the system should just reduce frequency some on its own.  But maybe that only happens down to the "base" frequency (3.4GHz). (Especially without hardware P-state management which was new in Skylake). And your CPU cooling isn't good enough for sustained operation of high-heat workloads at 3.4GHz?  i.e. it can't keep up with the rated TDP of the CPU.

Comment: "you mean like kernel log messages about the CPU hitting its "critical" temperature limit, and the CPU clock halting temporarily or dropping to idle speed to cool down?", "And your CPU cooling isn't good enough for sustained operation of high-heat workloads at 3.4GHz?" Yes, exactly you are right. Now, I choose to fix the freq to 2.4 GHz or 1.6 GHz with "powersave" governor.

Comment: What did I wonder is how to choose fixed freq to achieve best performance.